# Смена позиции пользовательского лейбла в процессе масштабирования через yandex map jsapi

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

На карте рисуется пользовательский лейбл, позиция которого высчитывается по координатам метки, к которой он привязан.

Пример рисования: https://jsfiddle.net/d1eL2h5m/21/

Проблема в том, что в процессе масштабирования от начала события и до конца запускается функция, которая высчитывает позицию лейбла, но если в конце масштабирования и в начале пиксели top и left позиции высчитываются верно, то во время самого процесса получаются очень большие значения и лейбл улетает в бок карты. При перетаскивании карты мышкой также высчитывается позиция лейбла, но при таком событии всё верно и лейбл всегда остается под меткой.

В процессе масштабирования позиция высчитывается таким образом:

```
_reposzoom: function() {
            global = YMYmap.options.get('projection').toGlobalPixels([55.752, 37.627], YMYmap.getZoom());
            var position = YMYmap.converter.globalToPage(global);
            offset = YMYmap.container.getOffset();
            this.options.set('position',{ top: position[1] - offset[1], left: position[0] - offset[0] - parseInt(this._$content.parent().outerWidth())/2}); 
            this._$content.parent().css({
                 left : position[0] - offset[0] - parseInt(this._$content.parent().outerWidth())/2 + 'px',
                 top :  position[1] - offset[1] + 'px'
            });
        }
```

Как сделать так, чтобы во время масштабирования лейбл не улетал в бок карты, а также оставался под меткой?

Comment: А почему просто не сделаете собственный макет метки сразу с лейблом, чтобы она масштабировалась и позиционировалась средствами API?

Comment: а какие есть варианты средствами API, чтобы был свой дизайн и метки, и лейбла, и еще чтобы можно было текст в лейбле менять, либо весь лейбл совсем скрывать (только лейбл)?

Comment: Можно сделать свой шаблон метки с/без лейбла и программно менять контент в лейбле и показывать/скрывать его. Макет надо будет запрограммировать, а все поведения уже сделает сам API. Пример кастомных макетов: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark_shape

Comment: Реализация шаблона для данного кейса в следующем ответе: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/856749/Как-отловить-событие-на-div-который-находится-в-шаблоне-пользовательской-метки#comment1380664_856749