# Как отловить событие на div, который находится в шаблоне пользовательской метки, но не входит в область ее активности iconShape?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Есть пользовательский шаблон метки и вместе с самой меткой там див, на который должен срабатывать клик. Например: http://jsfiddle.net/egz8p0o4/11/

Необходимо, чтобы заработало так:

```
$(".test").click(function(){ alert("click"); });
```

Но при этом, чтобы область активности метки iconShape осталась только вокруг самой метки. 
Возможно ли это?

Comment: Это выглядит как очень странное решение. Может быть кнопку отдельно засунуть например в хинт и сделать чтобы хинт появлялся при наведении на метку?

Comment: тут только для примера одна простая кнопка, в реальности это много квадратов, в которых располагаются данные и которые должны быть привязаны к метке и находятся от нее на фиксированном расстоянии и должны там же оставаться при зуме и движении карты. И на которые должен срабатывать клик.

Comment: а в какой момент они должны появляться, или они сразу открыты у каждой метки?

Comment: они сразу открыты и видны

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lc28s794/ Можно сделать так. Пример построения макетов https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/balloon_autopan